# Maximum Size a QPixmap Can Be scaled() to

Tags: c++, qt

Quick Answer: There is no defined maximum size. The maximum size depends on the RAM of the system.

*

I have a `QPixmap` pointer which points to a Pixmap drawn from a file in an actionOpen `triggered()` slot. Using this pointer I would like to scale my Pixmap using scroll bars and then add the pixmap to the scene again. Currently my scaling works however when I approach pixel numbers around 20,000+ the debugger tells me my pixmap is invalid and the graphics view widget displaying my pixmap does not display anything. I can't think of why this is the case considering that my Pixmap is originally drawn to be 30,000+ plus pixels and the graphics view displayed that in my tests (currently the program scales the pixmap down to (5000, 1000) and then the numbers approach 20,000 as the slider values change). I put together a simple button clicked() slot to test exactly what the problem was and the code is displayed below. Manually editing the numbers finds that my Pixmap will display with (6000, 2000) in the scaled() method but (20000, 5000) is invalid. Any Ideas?

```
    QPixmap pixmapTemp = wavesPixmapOriginal->scaled(20000,5000,
 Qt::ignoreAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    wavesScene->addPixmap(pixmapTemp);
    ui->PixmapView->setSceneRect(QRectF(0,0, 20000, 5000));
```

wavesPixmapOriginal points to a static pixmap defined in my actionOpen triggered() slot. It is a private class member of my mainWindow class, defined in mainWindow.h.

Comment: On Qt with the default backend, a `QPixmap` is a thin wrapper around a `QImage`. You're storing all of this image data as a single heap block. Most likely `QImage`'s heap allocation fails, since a 20kx5k image takes a gigabyte. This will fail on many 32-bit systems. Even on a 64-bit system you may run into trouble allocating these willy-nilly. **There's no reason for manual image scaling if all you wish to do is to display it**. For display, the image should be *painted* using a properly scaled painter - this will take care of resizing the image and you can zoom in as far as you wish.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to manually scale the image, or now I'm learning that I may have to use some sort of tiling method, if I need the painter pen to be at a constant width.

Comment: All you have to do is to paint the image on the widget with a proper painter transformation active. That's all. The image will be scaled as it's being painted on the widget, and only the visible part will get scaled. It's automatic and very helpful. I have no idea what you mean by "painter pen at a constant width" - you're drawing images, not lines. If you're thinking of scaling a vector image, then you'd be using a `QPicture` and then you could control the pen width independently.